# Installing DWM on gentoo

Tags: xorg, gentoo, nix, dwm

I was just trying to install dwm on my gentoo machine but I keep on encountering the same problem every time I `make clean install`. The error is...

`drw.c:5:10: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory         5 | #include <X11/Xlib.h>`

Most solutions to this problem are incohesive. I've also already tried mitigate this problem by installing [xorg.libX11](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=22.11&show=xorg.libX11&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=libx11) with nix. Anyone got any better ideas to this error?

Comment: Yeah I don't have the /usr/include/X11/ directory. Installing dwm with portage kind defeats the purpose since to customise it you have to edit the source code and recompile it.

Comment: Using "make install" defeats the purpose of having Gentoo or any other distribution by defeating any benefits of a package manager. Proper way to do that in Gentoo is to write patches to the software, write *your own ebuild* which applies those patches (you can copy original ebuild and play with it, or you can write one from scratch), configuring a *local overlay* where to put this ebuild and then install everything using Portage.